# Rotating map in ArcGIS Pro Layout?

Tags: layouts, arcgis-pro

How can I rotate a map to -28.5 in ArcGIS Pro?
Right clicking the Layout allows you to rotate like this:[image]

Right clicking on the actual map lets you rotate like this, but is very restrictive and does not let you type a value....
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the rotation field in your second screenshot you *can* type in a value, although it doesn't appear to accept decimals - `28` will work, `28.5` will not work.

It *doesn't* accept negative values, but you can just do range `0-360`, so closest you'll get here appears to be `331` or `332`

It also looks like you can use hotkeys `A` (counter-clockwise) and `D` (clockwise) to rotate the map view, and `V` which allows you to rotate using the mouse.  These will both rotate with decimals, but also don't seem to be able to type in a specific rotation value.